# How can i update from octave 3.8.0 to 4.0.0 on OSX?

Tags: octave, updates, osx-elcapitan

I have octave 3.8.0 installed on my mac. I want to install the image package but the command

**pkg install -forge image**

shows unmet dependencies and says octave 4.0.0 or higher is needed. So how do I update with out reinstalling octave?

**Edit 1:** I tried to install older version of image package image-2.2.2.tar but it has general and signal as dependencies. While trying to install general-1.3.4.tar I got the following errors:

```
octave:4> pkg install general-1.3.4.tar
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/mkoctfile-3.8.0: line 512:   423 Segmentation fault: 11  /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/g++-mp-4.7 -c -fPIC -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave/.. -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave -I/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include -pipe -Os -m64 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread SHA1.cc -o SHA1.o
make: *** [SHA1.oct] Error 139
/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin/mkoctfile-3.8.0 SHA1.cc

pkg: error running `make' for the general package.
error: called from 'configure_make' in file /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/configure_make.m near line 82, column 9
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/private/install.m at line 199, column 5
error:   /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/share/octave/3.8.0/m/pkg/pkg.m at line 394, column 9
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it doesn't address your modified question. I haven't tried this in 3.8.0 and I don't have time at the moment to make an attempt right now. If I get some time later I'll let you know my results.

Comment: How did you install `octave`?

Comment: I downloaded the .dmg file and it took care of the installation process @IKavanagh